# Problem with cdQA installation in Anaconda

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

I am trying to install `cdqa` in Anaconda using:

`pip install cdqa`

but it is showing error message i.e.:

```
ERROR:could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.2.0(from cdqa) (from versions:0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2) no matching distribution found for torch==1.2.0 (from cdqa)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try any of these commands pasted below should work

> conda install pytorch==1.2.0 torchvision==0.4.0 -c pytorch
>
> **OR**
>
> pip install torch==1.2.0+cpu torchvision==0.4.0+cpu -f
>   https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

**OR**

conda install -c pytorch pytorch-nightly-cpu

Comment: i tried this solution, but the error is still there :(

Comment: @Afianh  conda install pytorch==1.2.0 torchvision==0.4.0 -c pytorch

Comment: hi, still got error for that. perhaps, i would like to know, does this cdqa is compatible for Windows? Cuz, im trying to install the package in Windows